# extract values from a returned sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working in PHP.
I have a database that i pull data from.
I have at the moment the data output to a table.

My wish is to take this table and seperate the data to pass to seperate variables, do i some how pass to an array?

eg
original

```
Name          hours
Bob             4
Harry           6
Bob             2
Harry           5
Dave            1
Bob             2
```

Returned and in table

```
Bob             3
Harry           2
Dave            1
```

i'd like to take each value seperately as i wish
and also in row order so i then have variable

`Bob   = 3,
 Harry = 2,
 Dave  = 1`

and also take the values of 3,2,1

this will then be output and variables used to create a pie chart

Here is my sql query

```
    $dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName",$user,$pass);
    $query ="SELECT platform, count(*) FROM review GROUP BY platform";
    $sqlQuery = $query; // put your students table name
    echo $sqlQuery;  //helpful for debugging to see what SQL query has been created
    $statement = $dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare PDO statement
    $statement->execute();   // execute the PDO statement
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] ."</td><td>". $row[1];}
    echo "</table>";
    $dbHandle = null;
```

Comment: Please explain the current issue with your code. Errors? Undesired results?

Comment: There are missing closing HTML tags after `$row[1]`.

Comment: And you forgot to ask a question. Thus I vote to close this "question" as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name SQL columns in the query with `AS` and order it with `ORDER BY`: `SELECT platform AS plat, count(platform) AS count FROM review GROUP BY platform ORDER BY count DESC`

In the code where you fetch the results you can choose to fetch each row as an associative array:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {//this will fetch results and index them into the row array with column names:
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['plat'] ."</td><td>". $row['count']."</td></tr>";
}
```

This might be the easy way out, but keep in mind that you might want to order them differently later on. Also echoing out the results as you get them might be a bad design. A better way would be to store them in an array and later loop and echo it out. So here it is:

```
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//order the results the way you want here

echo "<table border='1'>";
//then echo them out:
foreach($results as $key => $result){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $result['plat'] ."</td><td>". $result['count']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

All in all here's the example with your code:

```
$dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName",$user,$pass);
$query ="SELECT platform AS plat, count(platform) AS count FROM review GROUP BY platform ORDER BY count DESC";
$sqlQuery = $query; // put your students table name
//echo $sqlQuery;  //helpful for debugging to see what SQL query has been created
$statement = $dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); // prepare PDO statement
$statement->execute();   // execute the PDO statement
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//data is here, just draw the chart

//you can access the data in the array like this: 

foreach($results as $key => $value){//$value is one row of results
    echo '<some html you="need" for the piechart>'.$value['plat']/*name of the platform*/.'</some closing tag perhaps><another tag>'.$value['count'].'</closed>';
}
$dbHandle = null;
```

Comment: You can replace the `while` loop in your second code block with `$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Sorry, force of habit, I usually get the id too and use it as array index so I can access the data later by crossreferencing it from another array:s with template engines

Comment: "... array sorting methods which are **generally** faster than let's say MySQL order by when the queries get more complex and row count increases" - I somehow doubt that.

Comment: Okay, I should be more specific I guess. array sorting methods are generally faster when using more than 1 sorting column

Comment: As I recall if 2 sorting columns are used some engines tend to use filesort after that

Comment: Filesort is used if no index can suport the ORDER BY clause. It doesn't matter if one or multiple columns are used. But do you really believe PHP uses a better algorithm to sort data than MySQLs filesort? Beside that, I would though separate data processing and data output. But that all is OT in the context of this question. We don't even know OPs issue.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a blind statement I made with vague information. I stand corrected

Comment: My point was tho, that in cases where filesort is used or the results can't be ordered by database by indexes one could develop own sorting algorithm with php that might be faster(not necessarily a built-in array sort)

Comment: "We don't even know OPs issue" i am in need of taking the returned data and separating into separate pieces of data. i would like to count the occurrences of each name and then be able to access the count and pass to separate variables

Comment: I think(with a bit of a stretch of my brain) he wants the data ordered and separated from the table, so he can generate a pie chart with it

Comment: You can use this answer to do it, just leave the echo part out and you have all the data in the $results array

Comment: Thank you for all your help and patience ;)